# Visualize Speed Control Effect Strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to visualize the effect of a **Speed Control** (SC) in the **VSE**? For example if I use a SC with a **Multiply Speed** value of 1.5 I want to see in the movie strip or maybe with a marker where the "new" end of the strip is. I know I can do this manually with cursor keys to check when the strip is over, but this is not very useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Manually place a [marker](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Markers).
2. Use (the default) *Stretch to input strip length* with *Multiply Speed* to 1 and set the *Trim Duration (soft)* end point of your footage to `length / 3` (for 1.5 speed).

Comment: The first solution is what I'm currently doing (and what I meant with manually), but the second seems the way to go.